# Overwriting persistence-model.xml won't work in orbeon

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I have tried editing persistence-model.xml in resources/config/persistence-model.xml and resources/apps/fr/includes/persistence/persistence-model.xml. However, none seems to be invoked? Is there any detailed and working example/tutorial online?

Comment: The second path you have there seems to be correct. Can you try introducing a syntax error in the file to see if it is being read by Orbeon Forms? As a bonus question, what is it you would like to do by overriding this file?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! :) I can't even produce systax error deleting bunch of lines (producing bad syntax) in persistence-model.xml (resources/config/persistence-model.xml and resources/apps/fr/includes/persistence/persistence-model.xml). I think persistence-model.xml in my war is not even considered, it just goes for the one in the jar. Do you think it is a bug?

Comment: Orbeon version I am working on is Orbeon Forms 3.9.1.201202031753 PE.

Comment: What I am trying to do is set an extra validation layer before workflow-send like 
<xforms:action if="instance('fr-persistence-instance')/is-error = 'false'"> <!-- Navigate to the confirmation page --> <xforms:send if="$is-send-navigate" submission="validation-submission" /> <!-- xforms:send if="$is-send-navigate" submission="fr-workflow-send-submission" / --> </xforms:action>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I think is that the path to this file in 3.9.1 is:

```
WEB-INF/resources/apps/fr/includes/persistence-model.xml
```

This should work!